# Regex for match parentheses in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of fasta sequences, each of which look like this:

```
>>> sequence_list[0]
'gi|13195623|ref|NM_024197.1| Mus musculus NADH dehydrogenase (ubiquinone) 1 alp
ha subcomplex 10 (Ndufa10), mRNAGCCGGCGCAGACGGCGAAGTCATGGCCTTGAGGTTGCTGAGACTCGTC
CCGGCGTCGGCTCCCGCGCGCGGCCTCGCGGCCGGAGCCCAGCGCGTGGG (etc)
```

I'd like to be able to extract the gene names from each of the fasta entries in my list, but I'm having difficulty finding the right regular expression.  I thought this one would work: "^/(.+/),$".  Start with a parentheses, then any number of any character, then end with a parentheses followed by a comma.  Unfortunately: this returns None:

```
test = re.search(r"^/(.+/),$", sequence_list[0])
print(test)
```

Can someone point out the error in this regex?

Comment: `^` matches the *beginning* of the string, which is why your search returns `None`. Similarly, `$` matches the *end* of of the string. Thus, your search will only ever match `"(foo)"` and never `"otherstuff(foo)"` or `"(foo)otherstuff"`. Get rid of the `^` and `$` and your regex will be free to find a match anywhere in the given string. Also, `/` is interpreted literally to mean "match `/`", what you're looking for is the *escape character*: ` \ . The comma right before the `$` probably isn't doing you any favors either.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Biopython which has a fasta parser implemented and allows you to access gene name easily.

Comment: I spent most of today reading up on Biopython, and you're right, it has a much better parser than the amateur thing I was trying to do.  I'm really glad you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any capturing groups,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = """
... gi|13195623|ref|NM_024197.1| Mus musculus NADH dehydrogenase (ubiquinone) 1 alp
... ha subcomplex 10 (Ndufa10), mRNAGCCGGCGCAGACGGCGAAGTCATGGCCTTGAGGTTGCTGAGACTCGTC
... CCGGCGTCGGCTCCCGCGCGCGGCCTCGCGGCCGGAGCCCAGCGCGTGGG (etc)"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=\().*?(?=\),)', str)
>>> m
['Ndufa10']
```

It matches only the words which are inside the parenthesis only when the closing bracket is followed by a comma.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/6)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\()` In regex `(?<=pattern)` is called a lookbehind. It actually looks after a string which matches the pattern inside lookbehind . In our case the pattern inside the lookbehind is `\(` means a literal `(`.
- `.*?(?=\),)` It matches any character zero or more times. `?` after the `*` makes the match reluctant. So it does an shortest match. And the characters in which the regex engine is going to match must be followed by  `),`

Comment: I'll have to look up why that works, since it's a little beyond what I currently understand, but thanks for the help.

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: Why so many ? are needed, the meaning of = and < in regexs.  I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape parenthesis:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\([^)]*\),', txt)
['(Ndufa10),']
```

Comment: I see I had the wrong kind of slash in my regular expression, which explains a lot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone point out the error in this regex? `r"^/(.+/),$"`

1. regex escape [character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) is `\` not `/` (do not confuse with python escape character which is also `\`, but is not needed when using raw strings) 
   => `r"^\(.+\),$"`
2. `^` and `$` match start/end of the input string, not what you want to output 
   => `r"\(.+\),"`
3. you need to match "any" characters up to 1st occurence of `)`, not to the last one, so you need [lazy operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+?` 
   => `r"\(.+?\),"`
4. in case gene names could not contain `)` character, you can use a faster regex that avoids [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) 
   => `r"\([^)]+\),"`