# Regex Match equal amount of two characters

Tags: python, regex, first-order-logic

I'ld like to match the parameters of any function as a string using regex. As an example lets assume the following string:

```
predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)
```

this may be part of a longer sequence

```
predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)
```

I now want to find all substrings that represent a function/predicate and its parameters (i.e. in the first example the whole string as well as the nested `predicate(foo(...), bar)`). The problem is that I cant simply match like this

```
predicate\(.*, bar\)
```

as i may then match more than the parameters of the predicate if the `*` is greedy, or less if it is lazy. Which is because such predicates() can be nested.

I need a regex that finds the string `predicate(...)` where `...` matches any string that contains an equal amount of `(`'s and `)`'s (lazy).

If it matters: I am using regex with the re module in python.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24696831/2272638) might lead in the right direction? Not enough coffee yet to prove/adapt, otherwise I'd post an answer :).

Comment: Python's `re` module can't handle recursion or balancing which you'd need here. Can you install the [`regex` module (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)?

Comment: @dwanderson that sadly doesnt work (or I dont get id) as it doesnt try to match an equal amount of parantheses, it just matches anything between a ( and a )

Comment: @TimPietzcker I should be able to install that package, yes, can you explain how i can use it to solve my problem?

Comment: Just a quick shot, using a subpattern repeat: `predicate(\((?:(?1)|[^()]+)*\))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the [PyPI package regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), as @Tim Pietzcker suggested, you can use [recursive regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html).

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)'
>>> pattern = regex.compile(r'(\w+)(?=\(((?:\w+\((?2)\)|[^()])*)\))')
>>> pattern.findall(s)
[('predicate', 'foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar'),
 ('foo', 'x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)'),
 ('predicate', 'foo(...), bar'),
 ('foo', '...')]
```

You could also constrain it to look for just "predicate":

```
>>> pattern = regex.compile(r'(predicate)(?=\(((?:\w+\((?2)\)|[^()])*)\))')
>>> pattern.findall(s)
[('predicate', 'foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar'),
 ('predicate', 'foo(...), bar')]
```

Comment: thank you very much! Is the recursion as easy as calling the group with (?2) in itself?

Comment: Yes. You just have to make sure the group contains everything you want to repeat. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def parse(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r'([^(),]+)|\s*([(),])\s*')
    stack = []
    state = 0 # 0 = before identifier, 1 = after identifier, 2 = after closing paren
    current = None
    args = []
    for match in pattern.finditer(s):
      if match.group(1):
        if state != 0:
          raise SyntaxError("Expected identifier at {0}".format(match.start()))
        current = match.group(1)
        state = 1
      elif match.group(2) == '(':
        if state != 1:
          raise SyntaxError("Unexpected open paren at {0}".format(match.start()))
        stack.append((args, current))
        state = 0
        current = None
        args = []
      elif match.group(2) == ',':
        if state != 0: args.append(current)
        state = 0
        current = None
      elif match.group(2) == ')':
        if state != 0: args.append(current)
        if len(stack) == 0:
          raise SyntaxError("Unmatched paren at {0}".format(match.start()))
        newargs = args
        args, current = stack.pop()
        current = (current, newargs)
        state = 2
    if state != 0: args.append(current)
    if len(stack) > 0: 
      raise SyntaxError("Unclosed paren")
    return args
```

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(parse('predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)'), width=1)
[('predicate',
  [('foo',
    ['x.bar',
     ('predicate',
      [('foo',
        ['...']),
       'bar'])]),
   'bar'])]
```

It returns a list of all comma-separated top-level expressions. Function calls become a tuple of name and arguments.

Comment: this is a way i already thaught about too but i wanted to avoid using so much code hoping it would be possible to solve it with a regex, especially as this may increase performance too

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex to find all of the function calls within your code. Something like this:

```
([_a-zA-Z]+)(?=\()
```

Then using the `re` module, you create a data structure indexing the function calls within your code.

```
import re

code = 'predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)predicate(foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar)'
code_cp = code

regex = re.compile(r'([_a-zA-Z]+)(?=\()')
matches = re.findall(regex, code)
structured_matches = []

for m in matches:
    beg = str.index(code, m)
    end = beg + len(m)
    structured_matches.append((m, beg, end))
    code = code[:beg] + '_' * len(m) + code[end:]
```

This will give you a data structure that looks like this:

```
[
  ('predicate', 0, 9),
  ('foo', 10, 13),
  ('predicate', 21, 30),
  ('foo', 31, 34),
  ('predicate', 52, 61),
  ('foo', 62, 65),
  ('predicate', 73, 82),
  ('foo', 83, 86),
  ('predicate', 104, 113),
  ('foo', 114, 117),
  ('predicate', 125, 134),
  ('foo', 135, 138)
]
```

You can use this data structure in conjunction with a `parse` function to pull out the contents of each function call's parens.

```
def parse(string):
    stack = []
    contents = ''
    opened = False

    for c in string:
        if len(stack) > 0:
            contents += c
        if c == '(':
            opened = True
            stack.append('o')
        elif c == ')':
            stack.pop()
            if opened and len(stack) == 0:
                break

    return contents[:-1]


paren_contents = []

for m in structured_matches:
    fn_name, beg, end = m
    paren_contents.append((fn_name, parse(code_cp[end:])))
```

In the end, `paren_contents` should look something like this:

```
[
  ('predicate', 'foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar'),
  ('foo', 'x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)'),
  ('predicate', 'foo(...), bar'), ('foo', '...'),
  ('predicate', 'foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar'),
  ('foo', 'x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)'),
  ('predicate', 'foo(...), bar'), ('foo', '...'),
  ('predicate', 'foo(x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)), bar'),
  ('foo', 'x.bar, predicate(foo(...), bar)'),
  ('predicate', 'foo(...), bar'),
  ('foo', '...')
]
```

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: same as with Markus Jarderots answer: its a way i already thaught about but i wanted to avoid using so much code hoping it would be possible to solve it with a regex, especially as this may increase performance